# Analyze if $(a+b)^{m} \equiv a^{m}+b^{m} \pmod {m}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

I need to analyze if $(a+b)^{m} \equiv a^{m}+b^{m} \pmod{m}$ for $m=2$ and $m=4$

For both values of $m$ i worked whith the definition of congruence.

- For $m=2$ works out and  then $(a+b)^{m} \equiv a^{m}+b^{m} \pmod{m}$
- For $m=4$  i have that

$4$ divides $(a+b)^{4} \equiv a^{4}+b^{4} \pmod{4}$ $\Rightarrow$ $4$ divides $4a^{3}b + 6a^{2}b^{2} + 4ab^{3}$ $\Rightarrow$

$(a+b)^{m} \equiv a^{m}+b^{m} \pmod{m}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $a^{2}b^{2}$ multiple of $2$.

I don't know if what i did is ok. Any other way to analyze this? Maybe a property of congruence?

Comment: $\ldots \iff$ at least one of $a,b$ is even

Comment: $(a+b)^pquiv a^p+b^p$ is known to be true for any prime $p$ independently of tha values of $a$ and $b$.